# Player Movement in direction of camera facing

Tags: unity, movement, multiplayer

I developing FPS multiplayer game.

I have my Player Camera that rotate Around the Player.

Player can touch the screen and rotate the camera using swipe.

My Problem is when the camera facing is change my player movement is not follow the camera facing.

when my camera rotate Left side to then player rotate to the left side but when i press my joystick button forward then player can't move forward can't change the moving direction of Player.

## That is my Player Script.

```
public class FPScontroller : MonoBehaviour {

// Should this script respond to input?
public bool canControl = true;
public GameObject lookObj; //This is root object that containc MainCamera, Weapons etc.
public GameObject joystick;
bool useFixedUpdate = false;


//Check when run, walk or when can run or not
[HideInInspector]
public bool Running ;
[HideInInspector]
public bool Walking;
[HideInInspector]
public bool canRun;
[HideInInspector]
public Vector3 rorationDir;

//Ladder variables
private GameObject mainCamera = null;
[HideInInspector]
public bool onLadder = false;
//private float ladderHopSpeed = 6.0f;

// For the next variables, @System.NonSerialized tells Unity to not serialize the variable or show it in the inspector view.
// Very handy for organization!

// The current global direction we want the character to move in.
[System.NonSerialized]
public Vector3 inputMoveDirection = Vector3.zero;

// Is the jump button held down? We use this interface instead of checking
// for the jump button directly so this script can also be used by AIs.
[System.NonSerialized]
public bool inputJump = false;

[HideInInspector]
public bool inputRun = false;

[HideInInspector]
public bool inputCrouch = false;

[HideInInspector]
public bool inputProne = false;

[System.Serializable]
public class  FPScontrollerMovement {
    // The maximum horizontal speed when moving
    [HideInInspector]
    public float maxForwardSpeed = 10.0f;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float maxSidewaysSpeed = 10.0f;
    [HideInInspector]
    public float maxBackwardsSpeed = 10.0f;

    //Run and walk variables
    public float WalkSpeed = 6.0f;
    public float RunSpeed = 9.0f;
    //Crouch
    public bool canCrouch = true;
    public float CrouchSpeed = 3.0f;
    public float crouchHeight = 1.5f;
    public float crouchSmooth = 8;
    //prone
    public bool canProne = true;
    public float ProneSpeed = 1.5f;
    public float proneHeight = 0.7f;



    // Curve for multiplying speed based on slope (negative = downwards)
    public AnimationCurve slopeSpeedMultiplier = new AnimationCurve(new Keyframe(-90, 1), new Keyframe(0, 1), new Keyframe(90, 0));

    // How fast does the character change speeds?  Higher is faster.
    public float maxGroundAcceleration = 30.0f;
    public float maxAirAcceleration = 20.0f;

    // The gravity for the character
    public float gravity = 10.0f;
    public float maxFallSpeed = 20.0f;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool enableGravity = true;

    // For the next variables, @System.NonSerialized tells Unity to not serialize the variable or show it in the inspector view.
    // Very handy for organization!

    // The last collision flags returned from controller.Move
    [System.NonSerialized]
    public CollisionFlags collisionFlags;

    // We will keep track of the character's current velocity,
    [System.NonSerialized]
    public Vector3 velocity;

    // This keeps track of our current velocity while we're not grounded
    [System.NonSerialized]
    public Vector3 frameVelocity = Vector3.zero;

    [System.NonSerialized]
    public Vector3 hitPoint = Vector3.zero;

    [System.NonSerialized]
    public Vector3 lastHitPoint = new Vector3(Mathf.Infinity, 0, 0);
}
public FPScontrollerMovement movement = new FPScontrollerMovement();

    void Awake () {
    if (GetComponent<NetworkView> ().isMine) {

    joystick = GameObject.Find ("Joystick");
    controller = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    standartHeight = controller.height;
    /*if(GameObject.FindWithTag("LookObject") != null){
        lookObj = GameObject.FindWithTag("LookObject");
    }*/
    centerY = controller.center.y;
    tr = transform;

    canRun = true;
    canStand = true;
    StartCoroutine(setupBools());

    }
}

    void Update () {
    if (GetComponent<NetworkView> ().isMine) {
        if (!useFixedUpdate) {
            UpdateFunction ();
        }

        movement.velocity.x = joystick.GetComponent<VirtualJoystick> ().Horizontal () * 5f;
        movement.velocity.z = joystick.GetComponent<VirtualJoystick> ().Vertical () * 5f;



        //Run input
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") > 0.1f && inputRun && canRun && !onLadder && Walking) {
            if (canStand && canStandCrouch) {
                OnRunning ();
            }
        } else {
            OffRunning ();
        }   

        //Check when walk or not
        if ((movement.velocity.x > 0.01f  || movement.velocity.z > 0.01f) || (movement.velocity.x < -0.01f || movement.velocity.z < -0.01f)) {
            RunAnimation1 ();
            Debug.Log ("Forward");
            Walking = true;
        }else if (movement.velocity.x > 0.01f) {
            Walking = true;
            Debug.Log ("Right");
        } else if (movement.velocity.x < -0.01f) {
            Walking = true;
            Debug.Log ("Left");
        } else {
            RunAnimation ();
            Walking = false;
        }


        if (!canControl)
            return;

        if (movement.canCrouch) {
            if (!onLadder) {    
                Crouch ();
            }
        }

        if (movement.canProne) {
            if (!onLadder) {    
                Prone ();
            }
        }

        if (onLadder) {
            grounded = false;
            crouch = false;
            prone = false;
        }

        if (!crouch && !prone && controller.height < standartHeight - 0.01f) {
            controller.height = Mathf.Lerp (controller.height, standartHeight, Time.deltaTime / movement.crouchSmooth);
            controller.center = new Vector3 (controller.center.x, Mathf.Lerp (controller.center.y, centerY, Time.deltaTime / movement.crouchSmooth), controller.center.z);
            lookObj.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (lookObj.transform.localPosition.x, Mathf.Lerp (lookObj.transform.localPosition.y, standartHeight, Time.deltaTime / movement.crouchSmooth), lookObj.transform.localPosition.z);
        }
    }
}

void RunAnimation(){
    GetComponent<NetworkView> ().RPC ("SysnAnimation", RPCMode.All, 0);
}
void RunAnimation1(){
    GetComponent<NetworkView> ().RPC ("SysnAnimation", RPCMode.All, 1);
}
void RunAnimation2(){
    GetComponent<NetworkView> ().RPC ("SysnAnimation", RPCMode.All, 2);
}

[RPC]
void SysnAnimation(int index){
    if (index == 0) {
        GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("Idle Aim");
    } else if (index == 1) {
        GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("Walk Aiming");
    } else if (index == 2) {
        GetComponent<Animator> ().Play ("Jump");
    }
}

 void OnRunning (){
    Debug.Log ("Run");
    Running = true;
    movement.maxForwardSpeed = movement.RunSpeed;
    movement.maxSidewaysSpeed = movement.RunSpeed;
    //Make bigger extra height when player run to increase jump distance
    jumping.extraHeight = jumping.baseHeight + 0.15f;
}

void OffRunning (){
    Running = false;
    if(crouch || prone)
        return;
    movement.maxForwardSpeed = movement.WalkSpeed;
    movement.maxSidewaysSpeed = movement.WalkSpeed;
    movement.maxBackwardsSpeed = movement.WalkSpeed/2;
    //Change extraheight value to default when player walk
    jumping.extraHeight = jumping.baseHeight;
}}
```

## That is my joystick Script

```
public class VirtualJoystick : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler,IPointerDownHandler {


private Image bgImg;
private Image JoyStickImage;
private Vector3 InputVector;

private void Start(){
    bgImg = GetComponent<Image> ();
    JoyStickImage = transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<Image> ();

}

public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped){
    Vector2 pos;
    if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle (bgImg.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos)) {
        pos.x = (pos.x / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x);
        pos.y = (pos.y / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

        InputVector = new Vector3 (pos.x * 2 + 1, 0, pos.y * 2 - 1);
        InputVector = (InputVector.magnitude > 1) ? InputVector.normalized : InputVector;

        JoyStickImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (InputVector.x * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 2.5f),
                                                                    InputVector.z * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 2.5f));

        Debug.Log (InputVector);
    }
}

public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped){

    OnDrag (ped);
}

public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped){

    InputVector = Vector3.zero;
    JoyStickImage.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
}

public float Horizontal(){

    if (InputVector.x != 0)
        return InputVector.x;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

}
public float Vertical(){

    if (InputVector.z != 0)
        return InputVector.z;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

}
```

## CameraRotate Script when touch to swipe

```
public class SwipeCam : MonoBehaviour {

private Vector3 firstPoint;
private Vector3 secondPoint;
private float xAngle = 0.0f;
private float yAngle = 0.0f;
private float xAngleTemp = 0.0f;
private float yAngleTemp = 0.0f;

void Start(){
    xAngle = 0.0f;
    yAngle = 0.0f;
    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);

}

void Update(){


    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {

            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch (i);

            if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2) {

                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {

                    firstPoint = Input.GetTouch (0).position;
                    xAngleTemp = xAngle;
                    yAngleTemp = yAngle;
                }
                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) { 
                    secondPoint = Input.GetTouch (0).position;

                    xAngle = xAngleTemp + (secondPoint.x - firstPoint.x) * 180.0f / Screen.width;
                    yAngle = yAngleTemp + (secondPoint.y - firstPoint.y) * 180.0f / -Screen.height;

                    yAngle = Mathf.Clamp (yAngle, -30f, 30f);


                    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
                    this.gameObject.GetComponentInParent<FPScontroller> ().transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, xAngle, 0.0f);
                }

            }
        }
    }


}
}
```

When i Change the Code Don't Understand.

If anyone have understand then help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Friends i Solve the problem of my question as i say above player movement using joystick based on Camera Facing.

In my PlayerScript there is two line read joystick input is,

```
    movement.velocity.x = joystick.GetComponent<VirtualJoystick> ().Horizontal () * 5f;
    movement.velocity.z = joystick.GetComponent<VirtualJoystick> ().Vertical () * 5f;`
```

In this Line i modify little bit, as given below.

```
Vector3 DirectionVector = 
            new Vector3 (joystick.GetComponent<VirtualJoystick> ().Horizontal (), 0f, joystick.GetComponent<VirtualJoystick> ().Vertical ());


        movement.velocity = transform.rotation * DirectionVector * 10f;
```

I am doing in previous code directly add joystick value in movement vector because of when time to movement that doesn't read player rotation, I just multiply it to the joystick input vector and solve my problem.

Now player move based on the player rotation and also when camera is facing.
Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this direction vector to move `Camera.main.transform.forward` - gives local z axis in world space of main camera. Or another way - use player `transform.forward`. No need for fancy calculations.

Comment: yes u also right , but in my player script some different methodology so i doing this for my script requirement for player movement. @Candid Moon Thanks for answer.